# Another H10 error while deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a problem to deploy a simple ruby on rails api on Heroku.

When I deployed my app (with gitlab CI), i had **this log** :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0 (0a75cdd1)
on docker-auto-scale (e11ae361)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:7015fc5d87110d5a132c5b6c18b20e90eb82411bc185f830f9dd394bc2dadf2a for predefined container...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.1 ...
Using docker image ruby:2.1 ID=sha256:223d1eaa9523fa64e78f5a92b701c9c11cbc507f0ff62246dbbacdae395ffea3 for build container...
Running on runner-e11ae361-project-4748707-concurrent-0 via runner-e11ae361-srm-1511735932-7447f02a...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/theodugautier/wsfcontender'...
Checking out 8d295d1d as develop...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ cd app/
$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0
1 gem installed
$ gem install dpl
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.43
1 gem installed
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$APP_NAME_DEV --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.2
1 gem installed

Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-0.13.1
2 gems installed
authentication succeeded
checking for app wsfcontenders-rails-dev
found app wsfcontenders-rails-dev
Preparing deploy
Cleaning up git repository with `git stash --all`. If you need build artifacts for deployment, set `deploy.skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Uploading-Files.
No local changes to save
creating application archive
Deploying application
uploading application archive
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 21833    0     0  100 21833      0   274k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  276k
triggering new deployment
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100    54    0    54    0     0     31      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    31
100    92    0    92    0     0     33      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--    33
100   269    0   269    0     0     62      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--    62
100   334    0   334    0     0     63      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--    63
100   396    0   396    0     0     69      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--    87
100  2159    0  2159    0     0    325      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--   429
100  2318    0  2318    0     0    276      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--   394
100  2318    0  2318    0     0    247      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--   406
100  2337    0  2337    0     0    227      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--   397
100  2357    0  2357    0     0    211      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--   361
100  2450    0  2450    0     0    209      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--    57
100  2450    0  2450    0     0    209      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--    39

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.8
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Using rake 12.3.0
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Using minitest 5.10.3
       Using thread_safe 0.3.6
       Using builder 3.2.3
       Using erubi 1.7.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Using crass 1.0.3
       Using rack 2.0.3
       Using nio4r 2.1.0
       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Using mini_mime 1.0.0
       Using arel 8.0.0
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using method_source 0.9.0
       Using pg 0.21.0
       Using puma 3.11.0
       Using thor 0.20.0
       Using i18n 0.9.1
       Using tzinfo 1.2.4
       Using nokogiri 1.8.1
       Using rack-test 0.8.2
       Using sprockets 3.7.1
       Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
       Using mail 2.7.0
       Using activesupport 5.1.4
       Using loofah 2.1.1
       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Using globalid 0.4.1
       Using activemodel 5.1.4
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using activejob 5.1.4
       Using activerecord 5.1.4
       Using actionview 5.1.4
       Using actionpack 5.1.4
       Using actioncable 5.1.4
       Using actionmailer 5.1.4
       Using railties 5.1.4
       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Using rails 5.1.4
       Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 40 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.0, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
       Bundle completed (2.57s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.0, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Detecting rake tasks

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compressing...
       Done: 22.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://my_api_url.com/ deployed to Heroku

No stash found.
Job succeeded
```

And when I used postman to fetch my api URL (with postman), I had this log :

```
2017-11-26T22:42:44.868503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/characters" host=wsfcontenders-rails-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=1d0860a2-a26f-42e9-90ab-58213e0357a9 fwd="90.44.177.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

so, i tryed to restart my app (restart all Dynos) :

```
2017-11-26T22:42:11.389014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-11-26T22:42:15.007314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45211 -e production`

2017-11-26T22:42:21.621084+00:00 app[web.1]: A server is already running. Check /app/tmp/pids/server.pid.

2017-11-26T22:42:21.661103+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma

2017-11-26T22:42:21.661106+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 

2017-11-26T22:42:21.661106+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

2017-11-26T22:42:21.661107+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting

2017-11-26T22:42:21.844594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-11-26T22:42:21.806442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

In my app :

My **Procfile** :

```
web: bin/rails server -p 45211 -e production
```

My **Gemfile** :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

ruby "2.2.8"
```

Any Idea ? :)

thank you !

Comment: I think the error is because your dyno is not running, turn on the dyno

Answer (score -1):

```
2017-11-26T22:42:21.621084+00:00 app[web.1]: A server is already running. Check /app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
```

this is your error. You already have a server running on your Heroku host. Probably you did not correctly restart that server and the `process` is still open on that `tcp` port.

When I have this type of error on local `ubuntu` development I do the following:

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

where `3000` is the port I am using. This command will return a list of process using `tcp:3000`

Then

```
kill -9 <processnumber>
```

where `<processnumber>` is the process you want to stop

I do this in development, but you can run this commands on heroku with `heroku run lsof -wni tcp:3000`

It could be an issue with heroku, they could be trying to fix it bythemself

Comment: thank you for your answer :)
When I ran **lsof -wni tcp:<myPort>**, Heroku said **lsof: command not found**.